# Zend framework redirection issue

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, authentication

My client moved a Zend application from another server and it has 2 errors in new server.

Error 1 - The login screen is loaded with below notice error.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/padcoser/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 75

Error 2 - Adter login it shows redirection error.

> exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/appdirectory/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php, line 75' in /home/appdirectory/public_html/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:323

When I checked with forum, they suggest to remove unwanted lines in php file after closing PHP tag. But it does not fix.

Please let me know your comments.

Comment: Ignore the second error, it's only happening because of the first. Could you edit your question to include the database configuration section of your application.ini (with usernames/passwords obscured). I'd guess that's where the problem is.

Comment: I could not find the application.ini, but it has Bootstrap.php for all setting other than database. I will add the PHP file shortly in my question.

Comment: I upload the Bootstrap file in http://115.112.70.158/zend/Bootstrap.txt Please check it

Comment: Is your database config in `application/config/config.ini`?

Comment: Yes the config file is in `application/config/config.ini`

Comment: @Senthil Can you post your /application/config/config.ini ? You can add dummy values if you like.

Comment: Please refer this link for config file - http://115.112.70.158/zend/config.ini.txt

Answer (score 0):

As per Tim's comments, I fixed the error #1 by downgrading the PHP version 5.4 to 5.3 and it is working fine now.

Thanks for all your comments.